# Erro em Web Service Java SOAP no GlassFish

Tags: java, web-service, soap, glassfish

Tenho o seguinte método em um Web Service SOAP rodando pelo GlassFish 4.1.1:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "CalculatorWS")
@Stateless()
public class CalculatorWS {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "add")
    public int add(@WebParam(name = "i") int i, @WebParam(name = "j") int j) {
        return i + j;
    }
}
```

Ao tentar executa-lo, o seguinte erro é retornado pra mim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O que devo fazer ?